# Importing subprocess executes print statement twice

Tags: python, subprocess

`import subprocess
print "Hello World!"`

The output I get is:
Hello World!
 Hello World!

print statement executes twice. Why?

Comment: There is other code in that file which you are running. You should post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want someone to be able to explain what happened.

Comment: That is all there is in that file. Just the import statement for subprocess and the print statement. If i remove the import - all is well.

Comment: If you have just one file named `x.py` with these contents and you run `python x.py` from the console, it will print *Hello World!* once. So, please explain what you do differently. Do you run some other file and then import this one? Do you have a file named `subprocess.py`?

Comment: Yes, the filename is subprocess.py - i was testing how subprocess works. Now i see why that is a problem. I have renamed the file and all is good. Thanks a lot, I wouldn't have figured this on my own. How can i accept your answer?

Comment: Nevermind the answer. Just remember to avoid naming your modules and packages same as a built-in module or package ;)